# Trying to start a listener socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I have tried to follow the exmaple on the MSDN to create an async server. But nothing seems to be able to connect to it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx

Here's what I have...

Also notice the AddressList[2], this is not a mistake ;)

```
private static Socket mListenerSocket;

IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[2], port);

// This line outputs 192.168.0.6:6809 (which is correct)
Console.WriteLine("{0}", localEP.ToString());

mListenerSocket = new Socket(
    ipHostInfo.AddressList[2].AddressFamily, 
    SocketType.Stream, 
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

mListenerSocket.Bind(localEP);
mListenerSocket.Listen(10);
mListenerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), mListenerSocket);
```

My callback mathod is defined as:

```
private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // It does not even get here
    mListenerSocket.EndAccept(ar);
}
```

I would expect when I telnet using 'telnet 192.168.0.6 6809' it should jump to the AcceptCallback method, but it doesn't, so a connection isnt established.

So any ideas why it doesnt work? The are no errors to help me :(

I have tried using a TcpListener instead, but again to still no avail :(

```
mListenerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
mListenerSocket.Start();
mListenerSocket.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), mListenerSocket);
```

Comment: In generall use better `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`. The classes seems to be easier to use.

Comment: Does `telnet` say `Connection refused`, or does it block for the duration of your TCP timeout?

Comment: "Could not open connection to the host, on port 6809: Connect failed"

Comment: 'no errors to help me' - then try to get more information.  If you explicitly bind the listener to 'localhost:6809' and telnet to it on the server box, does it work then?  If that works, try '0.0.0.0:6809' and try from another box.

Comment: @craig, this usually means nothing is listening on the target interface and port. Are you running `telnet` on the same machine? Is there a chance that a firewall rule would reject (but not drop) packets sent to the LAN interface on port 6809?

Comment: Tried 0.0.0.0, nothing. Tried on another machine (same network) again nothing. I have also disabled firewall, still nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My firewall was preventing connections to the client. Even though I disabled it, I had to restart Visual Studio to capture it.

Comment: When you run project in visual, firewall will ask you (only one time) allow for your program, you should tick accept for private and public network.